# How to pass command keys to a remote tmux session when you SSH from a local tmux session into a remove tmux session

Tags: linux, ssh, tmux

I would like to use my ssh tmux session inside my development tmux session, but it makes tmux behave bad (keys go to wrong session, etc). Is there a way to do it properly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set up

```
bind-key b send-prefix
```

in your `.tmux.conf`. By default all commands go to the outermost tmux session. If you press `<prefix-key>`<kbd>b</kbd> (`<prefix-key>`=<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> by default) the commands go to the inner session. Here an example:

```
ctrl-b   c  # create new window in the outer session
ctrl-b b c  # create new window in the inner session
ctrl-b   %  # create split window in the outer session
ctrl-b b %  # create split window in the inner session
```

Answer (score 10):

At least on my machines, I need to press "the key" (prefix-key) twice, to get a command to the tmux inside the base tmux,

So if I from a tmux window, I ssh into a server and attach to a tmux session as @Marco described above, I need to do these:

```
ctrl-b-b c # create a new window on the server (remote tmux)
ctrl-b   c # create a new window on my desktop (local tmux)
```

to make is super clear, `ctrl-b-b` means hold down `ctrl` press `b` twice then release and press the command key, `c` in the example above.