# Using tmux commands on ssh through a local tmux session

Tags: ssh, tmux

I have a local tmux session and I can do everything properly. Now I ssh to a remote machine and spawn a tmux session there. In the remote session, I would like to use all facilities like opening a new window, renaming a window, browsing through session-window tree etc. The problem is that whenever I use any such command, it is applied to the local session instead of the remote session! For example, `ctrl` + `b` + `,` to change the window name on remote, tries to rename the current local tmux window through which I have ssh-ed. This is true even when I have a blinking cursor in remote bash. How can I tell tmux that the command is to be executed on the remote machine, not on the local machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to setup the below part in your `.tmux.conf`:

```
bind-key b send-prefix
```

Now you can press `ctrl-b + b + ,` to change the inner session window name. Since by default all commands go to the outermost session, you will have to use the bind-key to access your inner session.

```
ctrl-b + b + ,  # changes name of inner session (remote)
ctrl-b + ,      # changes name of outer session (local)
```

I am assuming that `ctrl-b` is your default prefix key. By `ctrl-b`, I mean `ctrl + b`. 
`ctrl-b + b + ,` means that you have to press `ctrl`, press `b` twice and then press `,`.

You can further use `bind-key <key> send-keys <key1 key2>` to bind a key to send multiple keys together and access windows which are inside your remote instance. You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8530024/10153731) or this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17922171/10153731) for more information.